# ^ TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `U` is not a valid type at path `0`

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String
    },
});
    
module.exports= user = mongoose.Schema('user',userSchema);
```

Comment: please help me out

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `module.exports= user = mongoose.Schema('user',userSchema);` this line isn't valid. Where does the `user` portion come from?

Comment: Also, you're assigning a Mongoose schema to another Mongoose schema. It should be `mongoose.model('user',userSchema)`

Answer (score 2):

You are using [mongoose.Schema()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema) completely wrong. You should use `mongoose.Model('user', userSchema)` to create the User model, see [mongoose.Model()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You should use `mongoose.model()` function while creating the model and exporting it
i.e `module.exports= mongoose.model('user',userSchema);`
and second you dont have to assign it to a variable before exporting the model,
and you can directly access it using the name you are providing as the first argument in the model function.